# spark on yarn java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

My english poor , sorry,but I really need help.
I use `spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7` and `hadoop2.7.3`. and read log from s3, write result to local hdfs. and I can run spark driver use standalone  mode successfully. But when I run the same driver on yarn mode. It's throw

```
17/02/10 16:20:16 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n
```

`hadoop-env.sh` I add

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*

run hadoop fs -ls s3n://xxx/xxx/xxx, can list files.
```

I thought it's should be can't find `aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar and hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar`

how can do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using the same versions as you, but here is an extract of my [spark_path]/conf/**spark-defaults.conf** file that was necessary to get s3a working:

```
# hadoop s3 config
spark.driver.extraClassPath [path]/guava-16.0.1.jar:[path]/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar:[path]/hadoop-aws-2.7.2.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath [path]/guava-16.0.1.jar:[path]/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar:[path]/hadoop-aws-2.7.2.jar
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key  [key]
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key  [key]
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload true
```

Alternatively you can specify paths to the jars in a comma-separated format to the --jars option on job submit:

```
--jars [path]aws-java-sdk-[version].jar,[path]hadoop-aws-[version].‌​‌​jar
```

**Notes:**

- Ensure the jars are in the same location on all nodes in your cluster
- Replace [path] with your path
- Replace s3a with your preferred protocol (last time I checked s3a was best)
- I don't think guava is required to get s3a working but I can't remember

Comment: Thank your reply very much. But It's can't solve the problem.  I add  aws-java-sdk-[version].jar /hadoop-aws-[version].jar when I sumbit my driver,just like this:  ${base_dir}/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
--class com.csloter.xxx \
--master [master] \
--deploy-mode client \
--jars [path]aws-java-sdk-[version].jar:[path]hadoop-aws-[version].jar
--name DRIVERNAME \
${job_dir}/xxx-statistics_2.11-1.0.jar

Comment: the --jars option is not colon delimited, it's comma delimited so try `--jars [path]aws-java-sdk-[version].jar,[path]hadoop-aws-[version].‌​jar`

Comment: You are right. my fault. It's -jars [path]aws-java-sdk-[version].jar,[path]hadoop-aws-[version].‌​jar

Comment: That's ok. Did that fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Stick the JARs into `SPARK_HOME/lib`, with the rest of the spark bits.
2. `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem` isn't needed; the JAR will be autoscanned and picked up.
3. don't play with `fast.output.enabled` on 2.7.x unless you know what you are doing and prepared to tune some of the thread pool options. Start without that option.

Comment: I can't find **lib** dir under SPARK_HOME，I use spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7, I should create a new one?

Comment: There should be a  `$SPARK_HOME/lib` dir: if there isn't, on spark 2, then maybe is installed somewhere odd. Whichever directory has the spark-* and hadoop-* JARs along with all the rest (log4j, jackson, netty, kryo, ...) is where you should add the new JARs

Answer (score 0):

Add these jars to `$SPARK_HOME/jars`:

```
ws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar,hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar,jackson-annotations-2.7.0.jar,jackson-core-2.7.0.jar,jackson-databind-2.7.0.jar,joda-time-2.9.6.jar
```